# Admin user can't update WP

Tags: updates

I have a site running WP 3.3.2. The backend shows a bar saying "WordPress 3.5 is available! Please notify the site administrator."

Funny thing is that I'm logged in with an admin user, I double checked that. When trying to access the update page (at wp-admin/update-core.php) I get this error:

"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Any hints on what could be going on here?
Thanks.

Comment: Fresh install? Did you have any plugin that could have modified your admin's capabilities?

Comment: I disabled all plugins, but that did not help. I did not make a fresh install yet because I have lots of contents I would have to move to the new install. Will try that if there's no other solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make a new admin user in the db.

Follow these steps you should be able to create a new admin user, then update and then you can give your old user admin rights again. Or use the new user.

Your old user might have wrong setting in the DB

http://www.dnawebagency.com/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and I can add a new user. Unfortunately, the new user does not have update permissions either. Very strange.

Comment: Hi, thats strange. Have you tried download WP 3.3.2 manually and then write over all files (via ftp) (not the wp-config file). then try to update to 3.5

Comment: Great tip, that worked – thanks! I manually overwrote my WP core files and then could update to 3.5.

Comment: That was great news :)

Answer (score 43):

I had this problem once.

You should check your `wp-config.php` file and if you find this line

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);
```

change its value to false:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',false);
```

Comment: Perfect - a collegue set this on a site we manage mistaking it for DISABLE_FILE_EDIT. Similar commands so I suppose it is an easy mistake to make.

Comment: This work fine for me thanks for your help

Comment: this is must be accepted answer...

Comment: This is the correct answer. In addition to not being able to update WP, it also prohibits your from installing any plugins.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else with this problem, there is another line that you may have to find in your wp-config or functions file and change to false:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
```

Comment: This setting may appear in wp-settings.php

Answer (score 3):

WordPress was telling me I didn't have 'sufficient permissions' to update my own install even when logged in as the Administrator.
I had the following line in my wp-config.php file:
`define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);`
I was able to apply updates once again after I changed this line to:
`define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',false);`

Comment: This setting may appear in wp-settings.php

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to a file in your wordpress root and go to that page.

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-blog-header.php');

$role = get_role('administrator');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($role);
echo '</pre>';
```

Now, look for `[update_core]` in the text displayed. It's value should be `1`.

If not, add the following line after the `$role = get_role('administrator')` line to add the `update_core` [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) to the administrator.

```
$role->add_cap( 'update_core' );
```

Reload the page to see if the value of `[update_core]` is `1`. If it is `1`, you can try to do the update. Don't forget to delete the file you've added afterwards.

**Method 2:**

Get on PHPMyadmin and go to the `wp_users` table. Look for your user ID. Now go to `wp_usermeta` and change the `wp_capabilities` of your user ID to `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`. Do a backup before touching the database, just in case.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and got value "1" for [update_core]. But still, I can't update anything.

Comment: Added another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue once when updating a 3.9.19 installation.

I followed @RRikesh answer and everything seemed to be normal but still I can't run update.

It turns out a `define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);` was configured in `functions.php`.

So yeah, look for that line in your `wp-config.php` as well as `functions.php`.

Not sure if adding that line to `functions.php` is common practice since most answers here only suggest looking at `wp-config.php`

Answer (score 0):

Often you have to deal with giving your wordpress installation the correct file and directory permissions. If you can log into your server via SSH it is no problem at all.

1. Reset permission of all files to 664:

> find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

2. Reset permission of directories to 775:

> find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

3. Get user which is running Apache (User should be the first row/column):

> ps aux | grep apache

4. Retrieve the groups the user is part of:

> groups [username]

5. Reset the group to the group running Apache:

> chgrp -R [group] /var/www/html/

Now you should be able to update Wordpress automatically from your backend.

Answer (score -1):

This is a shot in the dark, but do you by chance have any mu-plugins that could be causing this? `wp-content/mu-plugins`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, I don't have any mu-plugins installed.

Comment: Normally plugins dealing with roles & capabilities shouldn't be put in mu-plugins folder. Roles and caps are set either on plugin activation or theme activation since they are stored in the database.

Comment: Plus, trying to access role objects before plugins loaded will generate a fatal error